# SQL Near error for inserting data through HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I've been trying to insert some data into my database for an events page. I have an html form and a seperate script, as seen below and the submit seems to go through for the `ename` `id` and `imgsrc` values but nothing past that. Anything more and I get a `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when, descr, positions) VALUES (`test`, 1 ,`www.vzdc.org`,`2017-1-20 23:59:00`' at line 1`I've done some reasearch but maybe it's just a weird error on my end? I'm fairly new to mysql and I would love some help! Thanks, code below.

```
<!-- HTML form -->
 <form id="newevent" action="insertevent.php" method="post">
                <p>Event Name:</p><input name="ename" type="text" width="100">
                <p>ID:</p><input name="id" type="text" size="5">
                <p>Banner Link:</p><input name="imgsrc" type="text" size="50">
                <p>Description</p><input name="descr" type="text" height="1000px" >
                <p>Date / Time (yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS):</p><input name="when" type="text">
                <p>Positions (ONE per line)</p><textarea name="positions" form="newevent" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
                <input value="Add Event" type="submit">
            </form>

/* PHP script on insertevent.php */
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "xxx");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$ename = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['ename']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
$imgsrc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['imgsrc']);
$when = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['when']);
$descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['descr']);
$positions = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['positions']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (ename, id, imgsrc, when, descr, positions) VALUES (`$ename`, $id , `$imgsrc`, `$when`, `$descr`, `$positions`)";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use back-ticks for binding variables to your query, use single ticks instead. You can use back-ticks for the table and column name:

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`ename`, `id`, `imgsrc`, `when`, `descr`, `positions`) 
VALUES ('$ename', '$id', '$imgsrc', '$when', '$descr', '$positions')
```

[`WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) is also a reserved word, so better change its name.

And since you're using `mysqli_*` API already, check [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I saw that prepared statement here and there, but know I know. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an SQL reserved word as a column name.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (ename, id, imgsrc, when, descr, positions) VALUES (`$ename`, $id , `$imgsrc`, `$when`, `$descr`, `$positions`)";
```

You really shouldn't, but if you want to get away with this, surround your table/column names with back ticks ```, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `events` (`ename`, `id`, `imgsrc`, `when`, `descr`, `positions`) VALUES ('$ename', '$id' , '$imgsrc', '$when', '$descr', '$positions')";
```

I've removed the back ticks you put around your values because, well, they shouldn't be there.

Please learn and use [MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). They'll help.

Comment: What is the difference between @LoganWayne's answer to yours?

Comment: I felt it wasn't really in-depth, so I added an explanation of **why** the OP had the error, plus some other elaboration.  No rule against that, is there?

Comment: Unfortunately your code also will generate errors, because you have not enclosed string variables in the query in single quotes.(and you have missed one back-tick)